# Is there a way to suppress PySerial output to stdout?

Tags: python, pyserial

I've got a working script that is using PySerial to communicate with a modem using AT commands. However, this communication is cluttering my formatted output as all AT commands sent and modem responses are echoed to stdout:

```
serial.write("ATE1\r")
```

Result on stdout:

```
ATE1
OK
```

I've tried to create my own output class which redirects sys.stdout and sys.stderr to my own descriptors, which works well with all output except for modem comm.

What I want to achieve is that all comm. is performed behind the scene so to speak. Perhaps I'm missing a parameter or something when setting up PySerial? Does anyone know how to suppress this output? Any ideas greatly appreciated!

Thanks
/C

Comment: how do you redirect the output, [by replacing sys.stdout,sys.stderr or at C file descriptor level](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22434262/4279)?

Comment: Within my output class Output (instantiated as "output") I do:
`self.stdout = sys.stdout
self.stderr = sys.stderr
sys.stdout = open(os.devnull, 'w')
sys.stderr = open(os.devnull, 'w')`. When I want to print something, I call my defined method "write": `output.write(text)`.

Comment: then try os.dup2 code from my answer